I have some problem with the inequality $\frac{-3}{2x+1}\ge2x+5$
I have tried to solve this problem
but I cannot understand why its solution is not identical to mine.
$$\frac{-3}{2x+1}\ge2x+5.$$
The answer given in the book is $$x\le-2\;\; \text{ or }\; -1\le x\le -\frac{1}{2}.$$
I can understand its answer if $y$ values of equation $(x+1)(x+2)$ is equal to or greater than $0$.
Why isn't it $(x+1)(x+2)\le 0$?

What $(x+1)(x+2)$ has to do with the inequality $\frac{-3}{2x+1}\geq 2x+5$?

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you remember that the inequality sign gets reversed when multiplying both sides by a negative number?  @Gonçalo:  if $2x+1<0$, then we have $-3\le(2x+5)(2x+1)=4x^2+12x+5\iff0\le4x^2+12x+8=4(x+1)(x+2)$

oh you mean, there are both cases that "if 2x+1 >0" or "2x+1<0", but if former case is, it is like contradictory because negative number is greater than positive number in this case, so i must think 2x+1<0... so should reverse sign.... right?

You haven't told us h9w you got the wrong answer, but my first guess is you multiplied both sides by $2x+1.$ But if $2x+1<0,$ multiplying by it would switch the signs.

We are given $\dfrac{-3}{2x+1}\ge(2x+5)$.
When multiplying both sides by $2x+1$, we must distinguish between $2x+1>0$ and
$2x+1<0$, because multiplying by a negative quantity reverses the sign of the inequality.
If $2x+1\gt0$ (i.e., $x\gt\dfrac{-1}2)$, we have
$-3\ge(2x+5)(2x+1)=4x^2+12x+5\iff0\ge4(x+1)(x+2)\iff -2\le x\le-1$,
but that can't be if $x>\dfrac{-1}2$.
If $2x+1<0$ (i.e., $x<\dfrac{-1}2)$, we have
$-3\le(2x+5)(2x+1)=4x^2+12x+5\iff0\le4(x+1)(x+2)\iff x\le-2$
or $x\ge-1$.
Thus the solutions are $x\le-2$ or $-1\le x\lt\dfrac{-1}2$.
I would say $x\ne\dfrac{-1}2$, or else the given would involve division by $0$.

thank you so much. i just miss that i must suppose two cases that if x>-1/2 or x<-1/2. that. i just think x>-1/2... because i haven't studied maths for 5 years since i graduated from high school... haha

Here we show two graphs, $\frac{-3}{2x+1}$ in red and $2x+5$ in blue.

The answer is where the red s above the blue:   $(-\infty,-2] \cup [-1,-1/2)$ .

The answer also includes the points where the red is the same as the blue, viz., $-2$ and $-1$

Good point, fixed.  But I still omit $-1/2$, which is where the left side is undefined.

HINT
There is no need to multiply both sides by $2x + 1$. Indeed, it suffices to subtract $2x + 5$ from the LHS and the RHS and study the sign of the resulting function:
\begin{align*}
-\frac{3}{2x + 1} \geq 2x + 5 & \Longleftrightarrow -\frac{3}{2x + 1} - 2x - 5 \geq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow -\frac{3 + (2x + 1)(2x + 5)}{2x + 1} \geq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow -\frac{4x^{2} + 12x + 8}{2x + 1} \geq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{x^{2} + 3x + 2}{2x + 1} \leq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{(x + 1)(x + 2)}{2x + 1} \leq 0 
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

$\frac {-3}{2x+1} \ge 2x+5$
Now, it is tempting to multiply both sides by $(2x+1)$ to clear the fraction.  But, what will happen if $2x+1 < 0$?
We will be multiplying both sides by a negative number, and that will cause the inequality to flip direction.  We will still make the multiplication, but we must keep track of our two cases.
Case 1: $2x+1>0$ or $x> - \frac 12$
$-3\ge (2x+1)(2x+5)\\
0\ge 4x^2+12x + 8\\
0\ge 4(x+2)(x+1)\\
-2<x < -1$
But that isn't consistent with the case we are in and we disregard this result.
Case 2: $2x+1<0$ or $x< - \frac 12$
$-3\le (2x+1)(2x+5)\\
0\le 4x^2+12x + 8\\
0\le (x+2)(x+1)$
$x\ge-2$ or $x\ge-1$
But $x\ge -1$ only holds as long as our inside our case.  i.e. $x< -\frac 12$
$x\le-2$ or $-1\le x < -\frac 12$
Why is it strictly less than $\frac 12$ while the others are less than or equal to?
Because the original expression is undefined if $2x+1=0.$  If the book show $-1\le x\le -\frac 12$ then the book is wrong!

@N.F.Taussig Thanks.

In case 2, you meant to write $x \leq -2$ or $x \geq -1$.  You also meant to say strictly less than $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Set $y:=2x+1$; Then
$\dfrac{-3}{y} \ge y+4;$
1)Note $y\not=0$;
2)$y>0;$
$-3\ge y^2+4y;$
$0\ge y^2+4y+3;$
$0\ge (y+1)(y+3);$
$y+1\ge 0$, and $y+3\le 0$ or
$y+1 \le 0$ and $y+3 \ge 0;$
No condition on $y$.
3)$y<0;$
We get $- 3 \le y^2+4y$ or
$0\le (y+1)(y+3);$
$y+1\ge 0$ and $y+3 \ge 0;$
*)Hence $[-1,0);$
Substituting back $y=2x+1$
gives $[-1,-1/2)$.
$y+1 \le 0$ and $y+3\le 0;$
**)Hence $(-\infty, - 3];$
Substituting back gives
$(-\infty,-2]$.
Put together
$(-\infty,- 2] \cup[- 1,-1/2)$.
